# Shorten a cell, nested Ifs Excel

Tags: excel

I need to shorten this but I don't know if there is a way to use like a "for" loop in excel

`=IF($B$1=1,COUNT(ABS!AG2),IF($B$1=2,COUNT(ABS!AG2:AH2),IF($B$1=3,COUNT(ABS!AG2:AI2),IF($B$1=4,COUNT(ABS!AG2:AJ2),IF($B$1=5,COUNT(ABS!AG2:AK2),IF($B$1=6,COUNT(ABS!AG2:AL2),IF($B$1=7,COUNT(ABS!AG2:AM2),IF($B$1=8,COUNT(ABS!AG2:AN2),IF($B$1=9,COUNT(ABS!AG2:AO2),IF($B$1=10,COUNT(ABS!AG2:AP2),IF($B$1=11,COUNT(ABS!AG2:AQ2),IF($B$1=12,COUNT(ABS!AG2:AR2),IF($B$1=13,COUNT(ABS!AG2:AS2),IF($B$1=14,COUNT(ABS!AG2:AT2),IF($B$1=15,COUNT(ABS!AG2:AU2),IF($B$1=16,COUNT(ABS!AG2:AV2),IF($B$1=17,COUNT(ABS!AG2:AW2),IF($B$1=18,COUNT(ABS!AG2:AX2),IF($B$1=19,COUNT(ABS!AG2:AY2),IF($B$1=20,COUNT(ABS!AG2:AZ2),IF($B$1=21,COUNT(ABS!AG2:BA2),IF($B$1=22,COUNT(ABS!AG2:BB2),IF($B$1=23,COUNT(ABS!AG2:BC2),IF($B$1=24,COUNT(ABS!AG2:BD2),IF($B$1=25,COUNT(ABS!AG2:BE2),IF($B$1=26,COUNT(ABS!AG2:BF2),IF($B$1=27,COUNT(ABS!AG2:BG2),IF($B$1=28,COUNT(ABS!AG2:BH2),IF($B$1=29,COUNT(ABS!AG2:BI2),IF($B$1=30,COUNT(ABS!AG2:BJ2)*IF($B$1=31,COUNT(ABS!AG2:BK2),0)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))`

Comment: `IF(AND($B$1>=1, $B$1<=31),COUNT(OFFSET(ABS!AG2,1,1,1,$B$1),0)`

Comment: ..but is that `*` in the last line a typo ?

Answer (score 2):

Use INDEX to return the end of the range:

```
=IFERROR(COUNT(ABS!AG2:INDEX(ABS!AG2:BK2,$B$1)),0)
```